# Is it possible to recode an EML file from Base64 to UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, base64, mime-types, eml

I have an EML file which contains Base64. Is it possible to recode it to be UTF-8? Headers:

```http
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Comment: Just base64-decode it…!?